# How to find all css files containing #page-title in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

I know `grep -irn "#page-title"` will search all files for matching text but for performance reasons I would like to limit the search ONLY to files that are css files. In Windows PowerShell it’s:

```
ls *.css -r | select-string "#page-title"
```

Bonus points, how do I limit this to files that are NOT prefixed with `css_`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find -name "*.css" ! -name "css_*" | xargs grep -H "#page-title"
```

find is the unix command-line find, with 2 sets of parameters. The first parameter, `-name "*.css"`, tells find to look for files with the CSS extension, the `! -name "css_*"` parameter tells find to exclude or ignore files that start with `css_`.    This list of files is then piped to the xargs command, which passes the list as parameters into the grep command, which is told to find "#page-title" from the list, and print the file name, using the `-H` parameter.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about what your code does?

Comment: @TomWijsman added additional detail per your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick

```
grep -r --include="*.css" "#page-title" ./
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. I just upvoted your answer but it could be improved by adding `--exclude="css_*"`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just uploaded grepcss: https://github.com/Red-Seadog/grepcss

grepcss understands CSS language, so you could do the find command as described above with

```
| xargs grepcss -s '#page-title'
```